# SCORM player in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

How to play SCORM content in flutter mobile application.
Basically this is used to make online learning more interactive and used in online learning application.
Got reference for web application not for mobile application.
I have done google for this but not getting anything for flutter mobile application.

Comment: have you find a solution?, Will you please share here? I'm also looking for same.

Comment: Still Not looking for an alternate option like xApi

Comment: use the embedded web view plugin. you will also need to interact with the SCORM JS api. But that is a JS question not a Flutter question really. https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

Comment: @TejaDroid No still not get a proper way to play scorm

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [scorm](https://pub.dev/packages/scorm) which is only available for the web.